# create a string from joining two arrays

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and currently working my way through code school. I've done this exercise before and have no issue with it, but after not doing anything for a week i decided to go back and redo some of the exercises... now i'm stuck on this one :( here is the instructions and below that is my code... what I'm I doing wrong code school tells me I'm not adding white space between the two words?

> Now alert to the screen the entire first movie in eightiesMovies, but only using the >eightiesMovies variable. For now, use the concatenation operator to unite the words into one >string. Remember to be attentive to necessary whitespace…
>
> var movie1 = [ 16, "Candles"];
>      var movie2 = [ 3, "Men", "and", "a", "Baby"];
>      var eightiesMovies = [ movie1, movie2];

```
my code
alert(eightiesMovies[0,1] + " " + eightiesMovies[0,1]);
```

Comment: Change [0, 1] to [0][1].

Comment: This has nothing to do with concatenating ***arrays***.

Comment: sorry I'm a beginner and thought the exercise was regarding concatenating arrays, I'm also new on SO so was that the reason why my question downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access an array in an array, you use two sets of brackets after each other:

```
alert(eightiesMovies[0][0] + " " + eightiesMovies[0][1]);
```

(Also you were using the same item twice instead of two items.)

What's happening in your original code is that you are accidentally using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), that's why you don't just get a syntax error for that code. An expression like `0,1` will evaluate both `0` and `1`, and then the value of the expression is the last value. That will make the code access `eightiesMovies[1]` which is an array, and the string concatenation would convert the array to a string. The result is `"3,Men,and,a,Baby 3,Men,and,a,Baby"` rather than the `"16 Candles"` that is expected.

Answer (score 1):

To [join the elements of an array](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp) to form a string use `join()`
in your example

```
eightiesMovies[0].join(" ");
```

Comment: Thanks we haven't covered join, will remember that method